# Mark parent where any child checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, treeview

I have a tree view of my categories and sub-categories. The tree is too long to find selected sub-categories under categories.

```
<ul id="user_tender_cat" class="treeview-black treeview">
    <li class="expandable"><div class="hitarea expandable-hitarea"></div>
        <span>
            <input name="cat_ids[]" class="cat-ids cat-id-1" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
            Agricultural/Forestry/Nursery Items
        </span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>
                    <input name="sub_cat_ids[]" class="sub-cat-ids sub-cat-id-2" value="2" type="checkbox">
                    Agricultural Machinery &amp; Equipment
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>
                    <input name="sub_cat_ids[]" class="sub-cat-ids sub-cat-id-1" value="1" type="checkbox">
                    Agricultural Pruducts
                </span>
            </li>
            ........
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expandable"><div class="hitarea expandable-hitarea"></div>
        <span>
            <input name="cat_ids[]" class="cat-ids cat-id-2" value="2" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
            Art/Craft/Entertainment/Fashion/Painting
        </span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>
                    <input name="sub_cat_ids[]" class="sub-cat-ids sub-cat-id-21" value="21" type="checkbox">
                    Advertisement &amp; Related
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>
                    <input name="sub_cat_ids[]" class="sub-cat-ids sub-cat-id-19" value="19" type="checkbox">
                    Band/Musical Instrument
                </span>
            </li>
            ......
        </ul>
    </li>
    ............
</ul>
```

Now I want to add an class to category span where any child sub-category is checked. I've tried some jQuery but still to get any good solution. So is there somebody to help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the change of any subcategory,Jquery finds the particular **parent category** using the selector functions and the `selected` class is addded to the parent category.Try reading more of `selector function` [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).Hope this might help you to some extend mate.. :)

```
$('.expandable .sub-cat-ids').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).parents(".expandable").find(".cat-ids").parent().addClass('selected');
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dLcg6kc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $('#user_tender_cat input').change(function(){
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('smclass',this.checked);
 }).change();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m954Lc8q/)**